# Getting ReferenceError: _dirname is not defined when trying to 'npm run dev'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Apologies if this is a very basic/novice question. I'm learning to use webpack/npm & node. When trying to 'npm run dev', I get the 'ReferenceError: _dirname is not defined'. I've attached snippets of my webpack.config and package.json.

```
const path = require('path'); 

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/index.js', 
        output: { 
            path: path.resolve(_dirname, 'dist/js'), 
                filenmae: 'bundle.js'
        },
    mode: 'development'
};
```

```
  "name": "forkify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "forkify project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "Banwo Idowu",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `__dirname`, with two underscores

Comment: Yeah, its `__dirname` not `_dirname`